# Populate WPF DataGrid with 2d array during run-time

Tags: wpftoolkit

I have 2d array with unknown size (nxm), how can i populate wpf datagrid with such a array.I found solution to create DataTable from 2d array and it works fine. 
Is there a way to populate it directly from 2d array?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Linq to union or join both arrays and directly pupolate the datagrid. It's similar to the DataTable solution, but shorter.